# Uncaught TypeError: gax.GoogleProtoFilesRoot is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, vision-api

I'm trying to use **google vision api** to recognize the text in image
**main.js**

```
const vision = require("@google-cloud/vision");
// Creates a client
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient({
  keyFilename: "./ApiKey.json"
});

// Performs label detection on the image file
client
  .labelDetection("./maybank2u.png")
  .then(results => {
    const labels = results[0].labelAnnotations;

    console.log("Labels:");
    labels.forEach(label => console.log(label));
    console.log(results);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("ERROR:", err);
  });
```

But when I view what I get in my console, this is what I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: gax.GoogleProtoFilesRoot is not a constructor

Comment: That error is not coming from your code, at least not from the code you've shown in your question

Comment: Did you install via `npm install @google-cloud/vision`? What version do you have?

Comment: @Phil ya installed

Comment: **What version do you have?** You can check your own `package.json` dependencies or open `node_modules/@google-cloud/vision/package.json` directly

Comment: @Phil version is 1.2.0

Comment: @Phil so do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Not a clue, sorry. You could try the ancient and trusted method of deleting `node_modules` and re-installing everything... `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json && npm install`